# Livewire only supports one HTML element per component. Multiple root elements detected for component

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have already a `livewire` component which controller fetch data from database and second component is product in that component controller i'm fetching product's data with pagination, but it will give me this error
**Livewire only supports one HTML element per component. Multiple root elements detected for component: [user-products]**

Livewire component controller `UserProducts`:

```
class UserProducts extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.user-products', ['products' => Product::paginate(5)]);
    }
}
```

Livewire component view `user-products`:

```
@foreach ($products as $items)
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="{{url('storage/products')}}/{{$items->image}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{$items->title}}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{$items->description}}</p>
            <p class="text-success">${{$items->primary}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

and include the component in products blade main file:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @livewire('user-products')
            </div>
        </div>
```

What i want to say is how can i fixed this issue...

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to add a wire:key to any iterable, or Livewire won't be able to easily track it.
It's also good to get into the habit of using forelse and empty in case you do pass an empty array.

```
<div>
    @forelse ($products as $productIndex => $productItem)
        <div class="card" wire:key="products-{{ $productIndex }}">
               
        </div>
    @empty
        No Products
    @endforelse
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In loop, like indicate Joe, it's highly recommended to use `wire:key`.
If instead, like me, you have something like this in blade template:

```
document.querySelector('#current-plan-body').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', 
`<div class="container">
   <span class="price">$${current_price}</span>
   <span>/Month</span>
</div>`);
```

The solution is to replace div my span (one HTML element only):

```
document.querySelector('#current-plan-body').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', 
`<span class="container">
   <span class="price">$${current_price}</span>
   <span>/Month</span>
</span>`);
```